# Ul not wrapping around image

Tags: css, image, html-lists

I have an image that is floated to the left that wraps text around it fine, however, I have a problem when a Ul and Li come into play. I wasn't quite sure how to explain this, so here is a picture: [image]

code:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
<center>
<h2>Ultimath V. 1.6.1 Released</h2>
</center>
<img align="left" src="images/ultimath_quadratic_tablet_land.png">
<center>Many new features and updated features, such as:</center><br>
<ul margin-left="15px">
        <li>Changed Search function to no longer bring you to homepage if not activated</li>
        <li>Multiple UI Fixes and upgrades</li>
        <li>Tablet specific layouts! (example to left)</li>
        <li>All inputs now automatically accept numbers (no more fumbling with switching to number keyboard!)</li>
        <li>Major Step by Step revamp! All solvers are now MUCH more specific!</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRONG:

```
<ul margin-left="15px">
```

CORRECT SYNTAX:

```
<ul style="margin-left: 15px">
```

Also try set up `margin-right: 15px;` for your image.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, I just kept changing things, I meant to delete that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float: left`, you should using `display:inline-block`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xYyaY/3/)**

Comment: and if I want the text to wrap, not just be separated like that? for example, once it gets lower than the image, I want it to continue below the image

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case you definitely want to go with float